# Will installing GNOME Shell affect Unity?

Tags: unity, 12.10, gnome, package-management

Is it possible to install GNOME 3 and switch between GNOME and Unity?

If I run `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell` will it remove unity, or break it?

I wanted to make sure, before I install GNOME.

My goal is to try out GNOME, without removing Unity. Or just to be able to switch between them. I've heard some of my friends talk about it should be possible at login screen?

Comment: No, installing gnome3 won't remove unity. You can switch between two even after installation. So, give it a try. :D

Comment: `gnome3` is not a package, Unity runs on top of the GNOME3 structure. `gnome-shell` is the package that installs the desktop environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Installing GNOME 3 won't remove any unity packages or break anything. You can just try it out and switch between your session in lightdm (the login screen). In the long run though, if you want to continue using GNOME 3, I suggest you use the Ubuntu GNOME Remix.